# JQuery Mobile popup freezes app on my phone... but not on any other device

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup, freeze

I am writing a jQuery mobile application and I wrote a plugin to display a popup. These have all been working in the past and should not be causing any issues now either. The thing is, only one popup freezes my phone, no others, Even ones using the same plugin. Also to make it more frustrating, it doesn't freeze on my tablet or pc. My phone is Android 4.1.2 and my tablet is Android 4.3.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the same problem, but you can try this:

```
.ui-popup-hidden {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: hey, um... how about you recheck your premises, wait for OP to actually clarify the question and then post this again, if it fits. and not just shoot something into the wide blue sky??